# optimal control constant

Tags: optimal-control, hamilton-equations

I have the following problem:

> $$ maximize \int_{0}^{T} [\rho \alpha s(t)x(t) - c(x(t))]dt $$
>
> subject to $\dot{s}(t) = -\alpha s(t)x(t), s(0) = s_{0}, s(T) = s_{f}$
>
> where $\rho, \alpha \in \Re$ and $c(\cdot)$ is a strictly convex
>   function.

I tried to solve it by setting up the Hamiltonian

> $$ H(x(t),s(t),\lambda(t)) = \rho \alpha s(t)x(t) - c(x(t)) -\lambda(t)[\alpha s(t) x(t)]$$  With FOCs:
>
> $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \rho \alpha s(t) - c'(x(t)) -\lambda(t)\alpha s(t) = 0$$
>
> $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial s} = -\dot{\lambda}(t) \rightarrow \rho \alpha x(t) - \lambda(t)\alpha x(t) = - \dot{\lambda}(t) $$

In order to solve this I need to show that $x(\cdot)$ is constant and I simply cannot get this from this system. If anyone sees this more clearly than me and could show me how to first show this or provide a hint I would greatly appreciate it. I tried solving the differential equations, and also using the system to get to a differential equation for x(t) but I simply cannot get to showing it is a constant.

Comment: The first term will work out as $s_f-s_0$, so we can focus on the second term

Comment: By convexity, $\int_0^1 C(x(t))dt \geq C(\int_0^T x(t)dt)$ also

Comment: The first term of which expression? @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: $\int_0^T \rho \alpha s(t)x(t)dt = \int_0^T \rho \dot{s}(t)dt =  \rho (s_f - s_0)$

Comment: Thank you very much @GeorgeDewhirst